# Front end for mysql db

Tags: mysql, user-interface

Hi have installed MySQL on my local PC. I want a  front end so that i have a GUI for creating tables, inserting values etc.

I know about SQLYOG but i don't know if its free/open-source. I want to use it in my office, so I can't use pirated stuff.

Any other tool for GUI?

Comment: sorry , i made a type in my original post.Corrected it now.Is SQLyog free?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I sometimes really like the [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/). It's available free for all the major platforms (Ubuntu, Mac, Windows etc. and the advantage compared to tools like phpMyAdmin is, that you

1. have a nice environment for designing your database and not only a tool for querying
2. don't need to setup a Apache/IIS for running the tool

Answer (score 2):

Use [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php), it's open-source & has some great GUI features.

Answer (score 1):

My choice is "Toad for MySQL". It is a freeware.
http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

try phpmyadmin.I think it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend one of standalone tools instead of setting up whole php/apache stack

i'm not using any of those but quick googling provides some options: mysql workbench, sql yog, sequel pro, heidi sql

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) if web access is required or I have LAMP stack setup, or otherwise I use [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/).

At work I also use [SqlDbx](http://www.sqldbx.com/personal_edition.htm) which is pretty awesome and does what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this tool, it is a nice graphic interface that will generate the needed SQL when you save it. You can then just run the SQL on your database.

http://code.google.com/p/wwwsqldesigner/

Answer (score 0):

You can download the free version of SQLyog here: https://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list